# template event to wait for subscription before collection.find

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor code allows the user to select from a drop down options list and uses the value selected to subscribe to a collection and return the document to display.
The subscription is not fast enough and thus I get an undefined when doing `myCol.findOne({person: fName})`.

Any idea how to fix it? thx

```
Template.manualSearch.events({
  'change select': function () {
  let name = $("#fName option:selected").html().toLowerCase();
    dict.set('person', fName);
    Meteor.subscribe('myCol', dict.get('person'));
    let personDoc = myCol.findOne({person: fName});
    if (personDoc) { // <=== always undefind
      let info = JSON.stringify(personDoc);
      document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = info;
    }  
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="manualSearch">
  <select name="nmnm" id="fName">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
      {{#each fNames}}
        <option>{{this.fName}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
  </select>

  <p id="debug"></p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a bad idea to subscribe in an event. That way you open subscription after subscription without ever cleaning them up. You should move the subscription into the `onCreated` callback and then use a reactive var like `Session` or `ReactiveVar` to update the subscription. That way Meteor takes care of the subscription lifecycle. Your return value should go into a helper.

```
// js
Template.manualSearch.onCreated(function() {
  Session.setDefault('person', 'some-default-name');
  this.autorun(() => {
    this.subscribe('myCol', Session.get('person'));
  });
});

Template.manualSearch.helpers({
  info() {
    const person = myCol.findOne({ person: Session.get('person') });
    if (person) {
      return JSON.stringify(person);
    }
    return null;
  }
});

Template.manualSearch.events({
  'change select'() {
    Session.set('person', $("#fName option:selected").html().toLowerCase());
  }
});


// html
<template name="manualSearch">
  ...
  <p id="debug">{{info}}</p>
</template>
```